# React/Redux app, JSON map outputs no data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a simple React application with Redux and have set up a simple api endpoint, where `/api/books` returns a JSON blob of books:

```
[{"id":0,"title":"Eloquent JavaScript"},
{"id":1,"title":"JavaScript the Good Parts"}]
```

I am using `axios` and Redux to fetch this JSON. Within a `BookList` smart container:

My Reducer:

```
import { FETCH_BOOKS } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_BOOKS:
            return [ action.payload.data, ...state ]
    }
    return state;
}
```

And my action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_BOOKS = 'FETCH_BOOKS';

export function fetchBooks() {
    const request = axios.get('/api/books');

    return {
        type: FETCH_BOOKS,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

However, within the React container, when I try to map over `this.props.books`, it outputs nothing unless I pass in `book[0].title`, and then this only returns the first book as I am specifying the first element, but I have no clue why the map isn't working.

(I am logging to the console `this.props.books` within the container's `render()` method. The output is two arrays, the second with data in, as follows:

```
[]
[Array[2]]
    0: Array[2]
        0: Object
        1: Object
```

My full container is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { fetchBooks } from '../actions/index';

class BookList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchBooks()
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.books);
        /*
            Outputs to the console the following:

            []
            [Array[2]]
                0: Array[2]
                    0: Object
                    1: Obeject
        */
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.books.map((book) => {
                    return <li key={book.id}>{book.description}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({books}) {
    return { books };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchBooks }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You're putting the `data` array inside another array. You probably just want one array right? `return [ ...action.payload.data, ...state ]`

Comment: Love you azium :) Why does the ...action.payload.data not put it inside another array? Unsure of how it is different.

Comment: That's what `...` does in this usage. It's called the spread operator because it spreads out the values of an array. `var a = [ 1, 2 ]; var b = [ ...a ]` is the same thing as `var b = [ a[0], a[1] ]`

Comment: @azium You should make that an answer